# In MS Word find the Heading under which a table is in the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

The folowing VBA problem:

I have a Word document with several chapters ("Heading 1"). At the beginning of the chapters there follows a table with information I want to process. 
It is easy looping through the "Tables" collection of the document to extract the information in the tables.

But how is it possible, to get the information aka "chapter name" ("Heading 1") unter which theses tables lie?

I need a way to find a "link" from the table in the "Tables"-Collection to the surrounding chapters name ("Heading 1"). So find the chapter  name ("Heading 1") using the information of the "Table"-Objekt in Collection (doc.Tables(1) --> "3. Chaptertitle 3rd chapter")

My idea is to search backwards from the position of the table until I find a range with Style "Heading 1". But how do I get the position information?

```
    Public Sub ImportRequirementsFromWordTables()

    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
    Dim iRowWord As Long 'row index in Word
    Dim iRowExcel As Long
    Dim iColWord As Integer 'column index in Excel
    Dim tbl As Variant
    Dim strCurrCell As String


    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

    'Set Titles in Excel
    Cells(1, 1) = "Anf.-ID"
    Cells(1, 2) = "Referenz"
    Cells(1, 3) = "Anforderungstitel"
    Cells(1, 4) = "System"
    Cells(1, 5) = "Art"
    Cells(1, 6) = "Priorität"
    Cells(1, 7) = "Beschreibung (optional)"


    With wdDoc
        TableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count
        For Each tbl In wdDoc.Tables
            'Check if it is a table with Reqs
            If Left$(tbl.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, 7) = "Anf.-ID" Then
                'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
                With tbl
                    'Find Chapter Name of chapter table lies in in Word and write to Excel
                    '????

                    iRowWord = 2
                    iRowExcel = 2
                    While iRowWord < .Rows.Count
                        For iColWord = 1 To .Columns.Count
                            strCurrCell = .Cell(iRowWord, iColWord).Range.Text
                            Cells(iRowExcel, iColWord) = Mid$(strCurrCell, 1, Len(strCurrCell) - 1)
                        Next iColWord

                        'Fill Description
                        strCurrCell = strReplaceSpecialCharacters(.Cell(iRowWord + 1, 3).Range.Text)
                        Cells(iRowExcel, 7) = Mid$(strCurrCell, 1, Len(strCurrCell) - 1)

                        'Skip to next relevant in Word aka skip one 
                        iRowWord = iRowWord + 2
                        'Skip to next in Excel
                        iRowExcel = iRowExcel + 1
                    Wend
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I know how to get all Heaadings form document, but I miss how to find chapter for table:

```
Private Sub getHeading(wdSource As Document)

        Dim docSource As Word.Document
        Dim rng As Word.Range

        Dim astrHeadings As Variant
        Dim strText As String
        Dim intLevel As Integer
        Dim intItem As Integer

        Set docSource = wdSource

        ' Content returns only the
        ' main body of the document, not
        ' the headers and footer.
        astrHeadings = _
         docSource.GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeHeading)

        For intItem = LBound(astrHeadings) To UBound(astrHeadings)
            ' Get the text and the level.
            strText = Trim$(astrHeadings(intItem))
            intLevel = GetLevel(CStr(astrHeadings(intItem)))

            Debug.Print intLevel & " " & strText

        Next intItem
    End Sub
    Private Function GetLevel(strItem As String) As Integer
        ' Return the heading level of a header from the
        ' array returned by Word.

        ' The number of leading spaces indicates the
        ' outline level (2 spaces per level: H1 has
        ' 0 spaces, H2 has 2 spaces, H3 has 4 spaces.

        Dim strTemp As String
        Dim strOriginal As String
        Dim intDiff As Integer

        ' Get rid of all trailing spaces.
        strOriginal = RTrim$(strItem)

        ' Trim leading spaces, and then compare with
        ' the original.
        strTemp = LTrim$(strOriginal)

        ' Subtract to find the number of
        ' leading spaces in the original string.
        intDiff = Len(strOriginal) - Len(strTemp)
        GetLevel = (intDiff / 2) + 1
    End Function
```

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Please, show the code you have already or try to solve this yourself first and then edit your question to include the part of the code you're stuck with.

Comment: See if this gets you started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737107/word-vba-get-range-between-consecutive-headings

Answer (score 2):

You can go thru document using
Selection.goToNext wdGoToHeading
Selection.goToNext wdGoToTable

That way you can rember which table is after which heading.
If you need more detailed code sample please ask, i'll provide it for you.

Comment: Can I get a sample please?